# Add character to beginning/end of various length string within file (Python/*nix)

Tags: python, string, command-line

I have a SQL file with dozens of SQL statements, where each SQL statement contains variables in the form of `$<variable_name>` (e.g., `$today`).  The variables are of various length, always start with `$` and can be followed by various characters (e.g., `.`, `,`, `)`, `:`, `\n`, whitespace, etc.), but the trailing characters are not related to the variable.

I am trying to replace the `$<variable_name>` with `@@@<variable_name>@@@`.  It's easy to replace the `$` with `@@@` at the beginning, but I am unable to find a solution to add the `@@@` to the end of the variable.

A solution in Linux command line or Python would be preferred.  I started tinkering around with...

`> grep '\$' file.sql | cut -d'$' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1`

And I could continually keep adding the `cut` with new delimeters, but that doesn't really present a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`sub`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function from the python regular expression module, [**`re`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
from re import sub

text = '$some_name,other stuff,whatever'

result = sub(r'\$(\w*)', r'@@@\1@@@', text)

print(result)
```

Gives:

```
@@@some_name@@@,other stuff,whatever
```

The regular expression `\$(\w*)` matches a groups, first `\w` matches any alphanumeric character or underscore, and the `*` means multiple. This group can be referenced as `\1`. We then build the replacement as `@@@\1@@@` where `\1` gets replaced by the matched characters.

If you want to apply it to a whole file, you can edit a file in-place using the [**`fileinput`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
from fileinput import input

for line in input(['file.sql'], inplace=True):
    print(sub(r'\$(\w*)', r'@@@\1@@@', line)
```

Comment: I tried your first example before the edit and it got caught on multiple variables per line.  I tried the new change it worked great.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I was trying it out. I'm not familiar with `sub` so my understanding was slightly wrong, and I'm not great with regular expressions. Testing is key, and I found a bug after posting.